# Whitelisting Problems?

Tags: whitelist, targeting

I have a huge issue that has to do with whitelisting. I have been doing C++ for about 6 months now and I can't seem to figure out how to pinpoint my targets to limit who can open and use my application with a whitelist.

For example, if the user is not on the whitelist the program would tell them by the way it loads. I would like to see this done with ID's if specific ID matches with the whitelist then that person can use my program.

I have tried doing target drawbacks such as getting IP's, but doing this is so vulnerable if the IP is changed. Also, multiple programs could be opened up on different IDs on that IP, which I don't want.

Sorry if this is very confusing I have just been STRUGGLING with this whitelist I have less hair than I did before I started making the whitelist.

Thanks if you can help, tried to explain the best I could! :)

Comment: It's not clear to me what a pacific ID is, what you've done so far, and what exactly is the question you're asking. Could you clarify, please ? Are you trying to find a method to uniquely identify users so you can match them with a whitelist ?

Comment: Yes, the ID's I know weren't clear, I would like them to match profiles for a certain site.

Comment: I think we're going to need to know _exactly_ what a "pacific ID" is in order to help in any kind of detail.  Can you provide a link to the site in question?  I presume this is an application that interacts very strongly with that site?

Comment: Other useful information would include:  How did a user who _isn't_ on the whitelist get a copy of your application in the first place?  What is the general function of your application, and what type of user interface does it have?  What operating system(s) does it run on?  If the user is not on the whitelist, is there some sort of registration process to get onto it, or are they SOL?

Comment: Finally, at present this question appears to have nothing to do with C++ (you're writing your program in C++ but that isn't enough to make this a question *about the language*) and I don't understand what you mean by "targeting".  You are far more likely to get good answers if you can apply more relevant tags.

Comment: remove c++ tag since it has nothing to do with c++. Instead add whitelist as tag

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP means a "specific ID" (I edited the question to this effect)

Comment: Yes this does have to do with C++ and I want a whitelist for anti-leak technology such as me selling a program I don't want my program leaked and given out for free to everyone else. And the site in question is: http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=21921809

Comment: I want that id in (http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=21921809) at the end to be on the whitelist and I can add others if they buy the program. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasKilian that did not help and I can't use that tag and it does have to do with C++ as I am writing the program in C++.

Comment: *such as me selling a program I don't want my program leaked and given out for free to everyone else* Copy protection is futile and counterproductive. Your program will be pirated anyway, and you will annoy the people who did spend money on it. Do not waste any more time on copy protection; instead, put your efforts into writing a program that does something genuinely useful, so that people *want* to give you money for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general strategy is pretty simple.

First, specify what criteria a user should meet to be on the whitelist.

Second, specify how data about users on the whitelist will be stored.

Third, when the program starts, gather information about the user - when the program starts - that can be compared against the criteria on the whitelist.

Fourth, when comparing data about the user with stored whitelist data, start by assuming the user is NOT on the whitelist and only permit access if a match is found.   If there are multiple criteria, you need to decide how to combine them to find a match  (e.g.  restrict a user to a specific IP,  allow a user only if using an IP in a range - which will prevent a user starting the program from home, etc etc)

Fifth, take steps to ensure your program can access the stored whitelist data, but users cannot modify it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to target specific users. First, I need some extract information.. How can you identify a single user ? Your program should be a connection toward any server ? In that case, your user should provide an id and a password or it's a anonymous connection ?

Comment: An ID, the profile requires one (like any other) and is shown at the end of the user profile. For instance: 199484

Comment: Another question, your whitelist is saved in the server-side or client-side ?

Comment: Server-sided as I don't want this to affect one client but multiple.